# Pose and Edit bones are not matching

Tags: rigging, bones

I mirrored my bones so i can have a simetric skeleton, problem is when i enter Pose mode, the bones are all messed up
What im doing wrong?[image: In edit looks just fine]

[image: And then in pose , its all messed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked to see if you have key frames stored on your bones? To check, select all and choose Pose>Clear Transform>All, and see if the problem continues.

Comment: I finally solve it, the problem was the IK had no chain length attached.
Thank you =)